# VSCode Python Intellisense remove default modules/paths

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense, pylance

I'm working on a simple python project which will be uploaded to an external micro computer running python (the Lego spike prime in case you know it). Because I'm uploading to a limited python environment, the number of supported methods is actually pretty small.

However, while programming, the Intellisense popup always recommends a bunch of unnecessary modules and functions which I can't use anyway.

I'm trying to find a way to exclude said unnecessary modules from the Intellisense recommendations.

[image: the recommendations I get]

It seems like the problem is because Pylance is always importing the modules it came bundled with. I am unable to figure out how to prevent Pylance/Intellisense from indexing these files. [image: path that is getting indexed]

I tried adding them in settings.json to the
`"python.analysis.exclude"`, `"files.watcherExclude"` and `"files.exclude"`
properties, and I also created a `pyrightconfig.json` file and excluded the paths in there, without effect.
I also tried to exclude some paths from within my project, which also didnt work (they were still showing up as Intellisense recommendations). This might indicate that I am doing something wrong.
[image: added files]

I also tried setting a virtual environment, but modules installed for the root user (like PIL) still get indexed.

I'd appreciate any help excluding the unnecessary recommendations. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no built-in way to customize the Intellisense recommendations to exclude specific modules in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: You said you've tried virtual environment. modules installed for the root could not be got if you select the virtual environment. You could use shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to change it. Running a python script will active the virtual automatically.